# PHP preg_replace() issue using ^ and []

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-negation

I have a small issue, and can not find a solution as of yet.

Here is my pattern,

`/[^a-zA-z0-9:,\s]+/`

This is working within a php preg_replace function yet for some reason the `^` and `[]` are slipping through the replacement.  I just can't wrap my head around why this is happening.

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A-z` seems to be a problem that matches many more characters like `[` or `]` etc

try this regex:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9:,\s]+/
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't even realize that was what A-z did. I assumed it meant a-z but case insensitive.

Comment: `-` acts as range so it matches everything from `A` to `z`